# Using find + sed to add markup to every SVG in a directory

Tags: text-processing, macintosh

I have a directory with a few hundred SVG files that are basically small icons. I want to add a `<title>icon name</title>` element to every icon using its filename as the content, replacing all hyphens with spaces and removing the extension.

As an example, here is the `arrow-down-narrow.svg` file:

```xml
<svg width="21" height="21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M10.5 3.625a.75.75 0 0 1 .743.648l.007.102v10.438l2.22-2.218a.75.75 0 0 1 1.133.976l-.073.084-3.5 3.5a.754.754 0 0 1-.078.069l-.006.004h-.002l-.008.007a.747.747 0 0 1-.081.051l-.015.008a.744.744 0 0 1-.11.045l-.009.003a.707.707 0 0 1-.221.033h-.028a.754.754 0 0 1-.046-.004l-.028-.003-.012-.002a.752.752 0 0 1-.085-.018l-.025-.007a.747.747 0 0 1-.068-.025l-.028-.012a.744.744 0 0 1-.21-.149l-3.5-3.5a.75.75 0 0 1 .976-1.133l.084.073 2.22 2.219V4.375a.75.75 0 0 1 .75-.75z" fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero"/></g></svg>
```

Ideally this update would result in the following markup:

```xml
<svg width="21" height="21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>arrow down narrow</title><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M10.5 3.625a.75.75 0 0 1 .743.648l.007.102v10.438l2.22-2.218a.75.75 0 0 1 1.133.976l-.073.084-3.5 3.5a.754.754 0 0 1-.078.069l-.006.004h-.002l-.008.007a.747.747 0 0 1-.081.051l-.015.008a.744.744 0 0 1-.11.045l-.009.003a.707.707 0 0 1-.221.033h-.028a.754.754 0 0 1-.046-.004l-.028-.003-.012-.002a.752.752 0 0 1-.085-.018l-.025-.007a.747.747 0 0 1-.068-.025l-.028-.012a.744.744 0 0 1-.21-.149l-3.5-3.5a.75.75 0 0 1 .976-1.133l.084.073 2.22 2.219V4.375a.75.75 0 0 1 .75-.75z" fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero"/></g></svg>
```

Is this possible?

I was toying with this which seemed to be heading me down the right path, but I’m entirely unfamiliar with sed and was running into a `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` error:

```bsh
find . -name "*" -type f -print | xargs sed -i '' -e 's:svg">:svg">HELLO:g'
```

Comment: You are on the right path, but I am not sure what you want to achieve with the `''`. Try again after removing it. My guess is that sed interprets it as a program. If you want to create a backup file, put the filename extension directly next to the `-i` without spaces.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you limited to find+sed? SVG is a form of SGML, similar to HTML or XML. Many scriping languages/tools (perl, python, tcl--all of which are usually installed on any linux base system) have extensions/etc for working with *ML data and using xpath to find desired nodes, _and_ can ensure it is correctly formatted. (I use tcl quite often, myself, and the excellent tdom package that is designed for tcl.)

Comment: Not limited, no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution. Searching for all svg files in pwd. Replacing the first > character with > + title tag information.
The filename from find comes prefixed with `./` which is removed in `$f`.

This will work, if all svg files are starting with the svg tag as shown in OP.
This will not work with spaces in filenames.

before

```
<svg width="21" height="21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none"...
```

after

```
<svg width="21" height="21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>test.svg</title><g fill="none"...
```

This is tested with one svg file, only. Make a backup of the original files.
Command in svg directory:

```
find . -iname '*.svg' -exec bash -c 'f=$(printf $0|sed s_./__);sed -i s_\>_\>\<title\>$f\<\/title\>_ $0' {} \;
```

Comment: Hmm. When I run it I get `find: alert-circle.svg: unknown primary or operator`.

Comment: Use single quotes on `-iname '*.svg'` (I have edited the answer to add them), so that the "`*.svg`" doesn't get expanded to a list of files/directories in your current directory. Debug by prepending `echo` to your command. `find` complains because the first parameter, `alert-circle.svg`, is a file, not, as `find` expects, a primary directory to be searched OR a `find` operator, like `‐type d`. Read `man find`.

Comment: I’m sorry… I spoke too soon. Now getting `sed: 1: "./alert-circle.svg": invalid command code .`

Comment: Restructure your problem! write a `bash` function to insert the string if it's not there already, wrap the function in a `bash` script that applies the function to each filename, `for filename in "$@" ; do ... done`. Invoke the script with `find . -type f -iname '*.svg' -print0 | xargs -0 -r $HOME/bin/script`.

Comment: I read that MacOs is having older or BSD versions of programs. That's a GNU GPL 2,3 licence thing and that it's actually a UNIX flavor not linux. However it's possible to install the latest GNU `sed` (and `find` I guess) with `brew` see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195590/is-it-possible-to-get-gnu-sed-for-osx#195595. Script will run, with the latest sed, find versions installed.